# Beginner Question: Mod Arithmetic Syntax Error

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

I’m trying to make a fizzbuzz program: count up to n; for each i up to n, print “fizz” if a multiple of 3, and “buzz” if a multiple of 5 — if a multiple of both, print “fizzbuzz”.

I’m using modular arithmetic, but for some reason my syntax is wrong.

Here is my code (without the “fizzbuzz” bit yet):

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
   for i in range(n):
      if i % 3 = 0
         return fizz
      if i % 5 = 0
         return buzz
      else
         return i
      
print(fizzbuzz(100))
```

Error Code:

```
Python3IDE(Python 3.7) running!
  File "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD2AF249-3788-42B7-90B2-929E9D35A2E1/Documents/FizzBuzz.py", line 5
    if i % 3 = 0
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Pytho3IDE run end!
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Note: the loop is pointless. Your return statement is going to stop immediately on`i==0` and return 0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `if i % 3 = 0` and the `if i % 5 = 0`. The comparison operator, in this case, would be `==`, so you would have to rewrite both statements with the *comparison* operator. Currently, you are using the *assignment* operator, which Python doesn't understand.

Comment: That's not the only problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you just missed out on some of the syntax.

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
   for i in range(n):
```

Note the double equal signs instead of single equal sign. A single equal sign is an assignment operator, while a double is a comparison operator.

```
      if i % 3 == 0:
         return fizz
      if i % 5 == 0:
         return buzz
      else:
         return i
  
print(fizzbuzz(100))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I do this, another error pops up: if i % 3 == 0
                        ^
It is pointing out the zero as incorrect syntax

Comment: There needs to be colons on the end of the if statement.

Comment: That's not the only problem

Comment: If you're talking about the returning undefined variables, I'm assuming that's because he hasn't implemented it yet.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong because you are using `=` instead of `==` to check is equal:

```
      if i % 3 = 0
         return fizz
      if i % 5 = 0
         return buzz
```

should be:

```
      if i % 3 == 0:
         return "fizz"
      if i % 5 == 0:
         return "buzz"
```

`=` is an assignment operator while `==` is equality operator.

Also, you forgot to add colon `:` at the end of each `if statement`.

And, you forgot to use `" "` on `fizz` and `buzz`. Python will search for variables with that name and won't find them. you want to return a string with `fizz` or `buzz`.

You should consider taking one of the hundred tutorials for beginners in python, that there is on YouTube...

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I do this, another error pops up: if i % 3 == 0 ^ It is pointing out the zero as incorrect syntax

Comment: You also need to add `:` at the end of each `if statement` like I did.

Comment: This isn't the only problem. fizz and buzz don't exist as variables

Comment: Oh wow, you are right, I didn't notice that. I edited the answer. Thank you.

Comment: It's a Good Idea to test answer code before posting it, just in case you missed something important. ;) But it's not a good idea to answer typo questions. They're rarely useful to future readers, so they get deleted.